# text-overflow ellipsis on one of two spans inside a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with ellipsis. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="firstText">This text should be effected by ellipsis</span>
    <span id="lastText">this text should not change size</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with pure css?
Here is what I have tried:

```
#firstText
{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

#lastText
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:visible;   
}
```

This is how it is shown:

*This text should be effected by ellipsis this text shoul*

While this is the result I want:

*This text should be e...this text should not change size*

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can give `width` to your `#firstText` like this :

```
#firstText
{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this example

### http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/5/

Comment: Worked better for me with max-width instead of width.

Comment: How do you resolve the issue with the vertical alignment?  one span appears lower than the other.

Comment: @Jeremy: either remove the "display: inline-block" on #firstText or add "display: inline-block" to #lastText as well. So in the end, both <span>'s either do have inline-block or do NOT have it. Correct solution might depend on your markup.

Comment: @ripper17, this doesn't work. In the jsfiddle both #firstText and #lastText are inline-block and yet they are not vertically aligned. Removing both inline-blocks also does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Jeremy: just add vertical-align:middle; in #firstText. Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68xgrqvm/

Comment: @Harshad Vekariya Thank you 'vertical-align' solved my problem!! 'vertical-align: bottom;' did the trick for me though

Answer (score 17):

You could achieve this by changing the order of your spans and give the first span a float right. That way you don't have to set a width to any of your elements:

```css
#firstText
{ 
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#lastText
{ 
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;
  float:right;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="lastText">this text must be shown in full</span>
    <span id="firstText">This text may be cropped</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic approach for when you can't give a width. `display: block;` seems to make all the difference.

Answer (score 13):

There's still a little case not handled:

When you have an unknown or a dynamic wrapper size and you want the first child to take all available space but ellipsis if it's still too long.

Here is my solution using `flex` CSS properties :

```css
#wrapper{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  max-width: 100%; /* or width:100% if you want the spans to take all available space */
}

#firstText{
  flex: 1;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#lastText{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="firstText">This text should be effected by ellipsis if wrapper is too small</span>
  <span id="lastText">This text should be fixed and not change size</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not get this to work as is (tested in IE 11).  Either the `max-width` should just be `width`, or the `inline-flex` should just be `flex`.

Comment: @Freezystem you're a legend, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could fake it like this: change your `span` to `div` and change your CSS:

```css
#firstText
{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

#lastText
{
    float: left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:visible;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to explicitly add the `width` or `max-width` property, here is how you can do using `display:flex;`

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#firstText {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#lastText {
  /* The text may wrap to next line */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="lastText">this text must be shown in full</span>
  <span id="firstText">This text may be cropped</span>
</div>
```

For ellipses we have to fulfill 2 basic criteria:

- Apply `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;` properties to the element you want to have ellipses on.
- Somehow constraint the width of that element, whether forcefully adding `width`, or `min-width` or using `display:flex;` or something else entirely.